# Copy file in Python - Read-write vs Shutil.copy

Tags: copy-paste, shutil, python-3.8, read-write

I tried to copy file using the read and write function I just learnt, as below:

```
from sys import argv

script, from_file, to_file = argv
a = open(from_file).read()
a = open(to_file, 'w').write(a)
```

Then, I googled a bit and found out there's shutil module that consists of copy and copyfile.

My doubts are:

1. How does 'read' function in the code above *acts* as 'copy' function?
2. If read & write function = copy & paste, why do we need `shutil.copy()` / `shutil.copyfile()`? In what circumstances do we use shutil.copy?